# Qlocale and brazil currency format

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

In c ++ I used to convert an integer value to the Brazilian currency format as follows:

```
QLocale loc = QLocale::system();
QLocale brasil(QLocale::Portuguese);
loc.setNumberOptions(brasil.numberOptions());
QLocale::setDefault(loc);

cout << brasil.toString(value * 0.01, 'f', 2).toStdString();
```

In PyQt, I did this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore
value = 225710000 #integer
lang = QtCore.QLocale('pt_BR')
print lang.toString(int(value * 0.01))
```

The problem is while in C ++ I had a output, for example: 2.257.100,00 (correct value for my case)

In python I have output: 225.710.000

Could someone help me solve this? Thank you!

Comment: The code you are showing does not produce that output. The output for `lang.toString(int(value * 0.01))` is `2.257.100` (which is correct). The output you are showing is for `lang.toString(int(value))`. Since the input value is an integer, it obviously won't produce the same result as the C++ example, which uses a floating point value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the same output as the C++ example, you just need to pass the same arguments to `toString`:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> value = 225710000
>>> lang = QtCore.QLocale('pt_BR')
>>> print lang.toString(value * 0.01, 'f', 2)
2.257.100,00
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved too with locale:

```
#https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') 
print locale.format('%.2f', (value * 0.01), True)
```